# What is a differentiable approximation to the indicator function a != b

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, indicator-function

I am dealing with an optimization problem where I'd like to regularize two parameters $a$ and $b$. The penalty should be $1$ if the parameters differ and $0$ if they are the same. The motivation is that a fixed transaction cost is incurred if the parameters are the same.

What are some possible differentiable approximations to $$f(a, b) = 1_{a \neq b}$$

Comment: I guess there is a lot of literature on approximating the 0-1 loss functions, which could be adapted to your problem.
My suggestion would be to use some of the kernel functions $K(x)$ often used and normalize them so that $K(0)=1$, then you can approximate $f(a,b)\approx 1 - K((a-b)/h)$, where $h$ is the band-width and controls the level of smoothing.
As example take $K(x) = exp(-x^2/2)$ and $f(a,b) \approx 1-exp(-(a-b)^2/(2 h^2))$
If you do not care about the differentiability at $a=b$, using the logistic function would be another option

Comment: @K.Hencken would you consider formulating your comment as an answer?

Comment: Thanks @K.Hencken, my worry is that the curve is very flat around $a = b$ which means that any optimization to find weights would easily settle for values of $a$ that are still slightly different from $b$ and send the indicator function straight to 0.

Comment: Maybe what I'm trying to do is not actually possible and instead, I should solve the optimization problem in special case $a = b$ and $a \neq b$ separately with different objective functions.

Comment: This objective is so radically *nondifferentiable* that any program of approximating it with differentiable functions is likely doomed to fail.  It sounds like you just want to force $a=b.$  Why not simply do that by using one parameter instead of two?